# How to remove node_modules from the pull request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github

So I contributed to a repository and initially the build failed so I contributed again but somehow this time I did something with the node_modules. I opened a pull request and now the github repo owner is saying to remove node_modules. I actually changed one file but it is showing something like 8k files changed. Being a newcomer I want to know what has happened and how to resolve this I.e how to remove node modules from the pull request and just commit to that one file only using git.

Comment: add `/node_modules` to .gitignore file

Answer (score 1):

I think you have accidentally pushed/added node_modules to your branch.

To remove it from your PR ->

You need to first delete that node_modules folder, and then commit that and push it to remote. That's it.

After committing the changes, you should reinstall the node_modules as we have deleted them. This time this won't be tracked.

Generally node_modules are untracked with .gitignore file, but there are ways to push it accidently.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps: 1) `git rm --cached -r node_modules`, 2) `git commit -m "Removes node_modules"`

Now you can push to your branch and the PR should be updated